# Unable to connect outlook in Microsoft365R: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)

Tags: r, microsoft365r

When I run, from the Microsoft365R library:

`outlb <- get_business_outlook()`

I get:

`Loading Microsoft Graph login for default tenant`

`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :`

`Send failure: Connection was reset`

The first line of the output is because I successfully logged into my microsoft account (authenticates through browser) but then it appears to hit a brick wall and I am unable to find specific guidance on what this might be. This is on a work machine so may be hitting some kind of wall there.

Unsure what the usual output would be, but I should be able to follow up by running something like
`outlb$list_emails()`

And that is not possible without having completed the get_business_outlook() function.